# How to create custom LOGIN and REGISTRATION forms?

Tags: plugins, users, login, user-registration

I have developed a theme for Wordpress and I need to customize login and registrations form.
At the moment, as usual, the login and the registration URL are:

```
http://www.example.com/wp-login.php
http://www.example.com/wp-login.php?action=register
```

I would like to create INLINE form, with INLINE I mean that this form must to be inside my pages and not in a single(dedicated) web page.

For login I need:

```
- Email 
- Password
```

For Registration:

```
- Name
- Email
- Password
(and a pseudo check for "spammers" like captcha or arithmetical operations)
```

as I told I need these forms in my pages, not in a dedicated page.

Two questions:

1- Can I do it **WITHOUT** using a plugin?

2- If I can, how can I show any errors (example: wrong email, wrong password) inline with the form? (without redirect to wp-login.php)

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 1. *Can* you do it without a plugin?

Certainly. Anything a plugin can do, you can obviously also implement yourself.

### 1.1 *Should* you do it without a plugin?

No. This is clearly plugin-territory. Even if you want to write the plugin yourself, this would be a better fit for a custom plugin than to incorporate it in your theme. That's a matter of preference and opinion though - of course it *can* be done within your theme also.

For the sake of completeness, let me mention Jeff Farthing's [theme-my-login](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/theme-my-login/). It's a well written, powerful plugin that has been developed for years. It is for sure the (much) less work-intensive solution and you should at least consider using it before you hack away on writing something similar (and most likely less powerful).

### 2. How can it be done?

Have a look at the [Administrative Actions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Administrative_Actions) and hook into those.

Again consider downloading the above mentioned plugin and dissect how it works.