# Is there any good tutorial to write custom login, registration and password recovery forms?

Tags: plugins, login, forms, password, user-registration

I like to have login and password recovery managed by my own forms and embed them into my theme.

I'm using the well written Jeff Farthing's plugin ["Theme My Login"](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/theme-my-login/) on some of my projects. But I would like to write my own custom functions and avoid the use of a plugin.

However I would also like to learn more on the process of making custom forms for logging in. While I might spending some time dissecting the plugin as suggested in an answer to a similar question ([How to create custom LOGIN and REGISTRATION forms?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/55585/how-to-create-custom-login-and-registration-forms)), I would like to know if there's any good tutorial, wiki or codex page which I might have missed that digs more or less deeply into user forms writing to have a better understanding of the subject.

I'd rather have the answer "no, there isn't any" than just "stick to the plugin", which is kinda obvious and repeated - after all, me and some others reading might have missed something different and new such as a well written article or tutorial.

cheers!

Comment: Do you ask for a list of links? That would be a shopping question. Please ask for actual problems you have.

Comment: I'll try not to be obvious then: ***The medium is the message.***

Comment: Too bad this was closed. I was about to write an answer with additional information. Linking to Customizing [Login](http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Login_Form) and [Registration](https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Registration_Form), quoting the introductions, to give an insight of which hooks can be used. Furthermore linking to [Administrative Actions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Administrative_Actions) to point to additional hooks. I'm thinking focusing on the **I like to learn more** part this should be valid enough. @toscho

Comment: @ialocin Feel free to ask and answer another question that is more on topic than this one. There is even [a badge](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/badges/13/self-learner) for that.

Comment: Ok! I just done that: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/117631/how-can-i-do-customizations-on-login-registration-and-password-recovery-forms @toscho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having done some research into Wordpress logins in the past, this is one of the few (possibly only?) tuts I could find where the author actually created a new login/register form.

http://digwp.com/2010/12/login-register-password-code/

Even so, he still uses the generic Wordpress wp-login.php code.

Re-coding the entire process is a big task. If you dig into theme-my-login you will see that it's a few thousand lines of code.

[wp_update_user](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_user) & [wp_insert_user](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_user) might get you started!

Comment: thanks gArn this is the sort of thing I was looking for and I failed to find using Google before... therefore I made a question here, thanks for getting to the point and sharing your resource with me (and the rest of the readers). Update: I gave a closer look, eventually doesn't cover everything and doesn't explain certain things I was looking for (well I guess I will have to dig and examine single articles in the codex more carefully), however it's sort of good that it uses the generic wp-login, I don't want to build something too complicated... maybe your link is a good starting point