# How can I do customizations on login, registration and password recovery forms?

Tags: hooks, login, user-registration, wp-login-form, codex

There are a couple of answers here basically just linking to a plugin - to be fair there are some more specific ones too. I know there are many possibilities to use different hooks for the customization. I really want to learn more about that, but where do it start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an general overview about hooks take a look at the codex page about the [Plugin API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/):

> This article is specifically about the API of "Hooks", also known as "Filters" and "Actions"

Besides that there is valuable information specifically about *customizing the login and registration form* available at the codex:

**[Customizing the Login Form](http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Login_Form)**

> You can customize your WordPress login page with action hooks and
>   filter hooks, including:
>
> - Actions in the  of the document: login_enqueue_scripts, login_head.
> - Filters in the : login_headerurl, login_headertitle, login_message, login_errors.
> - Actions at the bottom of and below the form: login_form, login_footer.

**[Customizing The Registration Form](https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Registration_Form)**

> Theme and plugin developers can customize WordPress's built-in user
>   registration page through the use of hooks.
>
> Customizing the registration form involves utilizing the following
>   three hooks:
>
> 1. register_form
>      Allows rendering of new HTML form elements.
> 2. registration_errors
>      Perform validation on form registration fields.
> 3. user_register
>      Save custom form data.

The information given above should get you started learning more about customizing those forms - besides that there are some good examples available too. Especially you get an first overview about the hooks you can use.
But those aren't all there are, so additionally take a look at the other available hooks for [Adminstrative Actions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Administrative_Actions) you can use for further customizations of those forms. Not all of them are documented well (or at all), so it might be necessary to take a look at the source, for example [wp-login.php](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3.6-branch/wp-login.php) and [general-template.php](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3.6-branch/wp-includes/general-template.php) - those are the sources for the 3.6 branch.