# Admin Hook at the Login Page

Tags: hooks, actions

I need to write code before user can enter username and password. So, I have code written just after the following line in wp-login.php page:

```
$action = isset($_REQUEST['action']) ? $_REQUEST['action'] : 'login';
```

The above line is somewhere # 372.

My line:

```
if ($action == 'login') {
   // My code
}
```

When done like this, script run before even username and pwd box comes. I am thinking of adding hook etc so that I do not need to modify wp-login.php page.

Any idea?

Comment: I see wp_login and login_form but not sure about these. I prefer my code execute before user are present with login form.

Comment: You might want to take a look at this : [How can I do customizations on login, registration and password recovery forms?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/117631/how-can-i-do-customizations-on-login-registration-and-password-recovery-forms/117632#117632)

Answer (score 8):

If you don't care about the actual action you can use `login_init` action like this:

```
add_action( 'login_init', 'wpse8170_login_init' );
function wpse8170_login_init() {
    // do your stuff here
}
```

But if you want to handle only special actions, then you need to hook into `login_form_{action}` action, like this:

```
add_action( 'login_form_login', 'wpse8170_login_form_login' );
function wpse8170_login_form_login() {
    // do your login stuff here
}
```

Or like this:

```
add_action( 'login_form_register', 'wpse8170_login_form_register' );
function wpse8170_login_form_register() {
    // do your register stuff here
}
```

If you need to add some CSS or JS to your login page, then you need to use `login_enqueue_scripts` action:

```
add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse8170_login_enqueue_scripts' );
function wpse8170_login_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( ... );
    wp_enqueue_style( ... );
}
```

Comment: Actually, these actions restricts something and leave something. I know if I could paste code then that would be helpful. My code was checking something in URL if it was there then page comes nicely (usual login page) but in these scenarios, it looks css or something does not comes. So, form comes at the top right corner.

Comment: I have udpated my answer and added `login_enqueue_scripts` action hook. Check it out!

Comment: Thank you, Eugene. I think it won't work. Voted up for your best effort. I have PHP after that line I have mentioned and above 3 hooks you have given did not work as expected so, possibly I need to live with wp-login.php file change. In the PHP just below that line, I check for cookie and url parameter, if that neither match then I exit. That is Security related stuff.