# How can I customize the content of the login page?

Tags: login, forms

I would like to customize the login-form page.

Is there a way as with the function `get_the_content()` for the article to get the content of the login page before it's send for output?

Comment: Plug-in recommendations are off topic, so I removed that part. Additionally it is a bit unclear what exactly you want, you should specify. Maybe you are looking for [this information](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/117631/22534).

Answer (score 0):

There is `wp_loginout()` which will get you a simple login/logout form, and that content is filterable with the `loginout` hook, but the "login-form page" (by which I think you mean `wp-login.php`) is [mostly hard-coded](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4/src/wp-login.php). There are a lot of hook in there that might be enough to do what you want though-- twenty-three hooks by my very sloppy count, so I'm not going to enumerate them. That doesn't count hooks in functions not in that file.