# Include "registration.php" for custom registration form?

Tags: user-registration

I’m creating a custom registration form for my website. Every tutorial has this call in the form

```
require_once(ABSPATH . WPINC . '/registration.php');
```

I’ve read that `registration.php` has been depreciated quite a long time ago. Which file must be called upon, what is the proper way?

Comment: Are you trying to create a registration form outside of WordPress and store the users in the WP database or will your form be inside WordPress?  You don't need to include anything if you're inside WordPress.

Comment: my registration form will be outside wp and yes, the new users will be saved in the wp database

Comment: I'm not well versed with Registration form. But I found this code `<?php require_once(ABSPATH . WPINC . '/registration.php' ); require_once(ABSPATH . WPINC . '/pluggable.php' ); ?>` in [Simplr Registration Form plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simplr-registration-form/‎).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create custom LOGIN and REGISTRATION forms?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/55585/how-to-create-custom-login-and-registration-forms)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[If you look at the source of the file](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/registration.php) you can see that it doesn't do anything even if you were to include it except add a warning that "This file no longer needs to be included". So those tutorials are out of date. You don't need to include it.

The file you actually need to `include`, if any file at all, depends on what you want to do *exactly*, and you don't explain that in the question. A number of registration functions are in [`wp-login.php`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-login.php) which is very inconvenient because you can `include` that file to get at the functions without also getting a bunch of `echo`ed HTML as well.

Comment: i just want to create a registration form on one of my website's page templates and add a few fields to the form

Comment: There are a number of "custom registration form" questions here. Check those out. Look to the right under "Related" to get started.